# Run a function multiple times and then return all the different results?

Tags: python, function, loops, names

Here is my code:

```
import random
def name_generator():
    for x in range (0, 11):
        color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
        animal = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
        number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

        randomColor = random.randrange(0, len(color))
        randomAnimal = random.randrange(0, len(animal))
        randomNumber = random.randrange(0, len(number))

        name = "Username: " + color[randomColor] + animal[randomAnimal] + number[randomNumber]
        return name
```

I'm trying to generate ten different names and then print all the different names. Now when I'm running the function I'm only getting one name returned instead of ten different names.

```
for x in range (0, 11)
```

This should execute the function ten times as far as I understand?

This is the result I'm getting now:

```
name_generator()
'Username: PurpleLeopard13'
```

But I'm trying to get:

```
name_generator()
'Username: PurpleLeopard13'
'Username: GreenDog10'
'Username: PurpleCat1'...(10 times)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You call your function `name_generator`... are you actually trying to create a generator function you can loop over? If so, you probably want `yield` instead of `return` - that or do as the answer sense and call it 10 times...

Comment: On a side note - for picking a single element - instead of `random.randrange(0, len(whatever))` and using that to index into `whatever`... you can just use `random_color = random.choice(color)` and then `random_color` will be one of the colours in the list... much clearer and simpler.

Comment: I agree with @JonClements. Either turn it into an actual generator and yield the results, or make an internal list, append results to the list in the loop, and return the final list. This depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that currently you have put the return statement inside the for loop. So as soon as you generate the first name, you return and leave the function.

You need a slight modification: Move the function call inside the for loop. Alternatively, follow the suggestion of @Jon Clements in the comments below.

```
import random
def name_generator():
        color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
        animal = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
        number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

        randomColor = random.randrange(0, len(color))
        randomAnimal = random.randrange(0, len(animal))
        randomNumber = random.randrange(0, len(number))

        name = "Username: " + color[randomColor] + animal[randomAnimal] + number[randomNumber]
        return name

for x in range (0, 11):    
    print (name_generator())

# Username: PinkMouse3
# Username: GreenCat8
# Username: GreenMoose2
# Username: BlackTiger14
# Username: BlackSnake11
# Username: PurpleMoose13
# Username: GreenMouse2
# Username: RedBear5
# Username: BlueBear2
# Username: WhiteDog2
# Username: WhiteTiger3
```

Comment: That or they want to `yield name` and then `for name in name_generator(): print(name)`... or `print(*name_generator(), sep='\n')` or whatever....

Comment: @JonClements: The function name is ambiguous here. But I think I tried to explain what is going wrong with his/her code. I hope the OP learn something from this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Instead of return in for loop try to use print. Your return prevents the loop to interate further.

```
import random
def name_generator():
    for x in range (0, 11):
        color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
        animal = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
        number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

        randomColor = random.randrange(0, len(color))
        randomAnimal = random.randrange(0, len(animal))
        randomNumber = random.randrange(0, len(number))

        name = "Username: " + color[randomColor] + animal[randomAnimal] + number[randomNumber]

        print(name)

name_generator()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an additional riff on the use of a generator, make your generator capable of providing an *arbitrary* number of names. The user can decide how many names too retrieve.

```
from random import choice
from itertools import islice

def name_generator():
    colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
    animals = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

    while True:
        yield "Username: {}{}{}".format(
           choice(colors),
           choice(animals),
           choice(numbers)
        )


names = list(islice(name_generator(), 10))
```